# Almost sure convergence implications with expected value

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Let $(X_n)_n\in\mathbb{N}$ be independent identically distributed random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$. Let $\beta  \in (1,2)$. Show that if $n^{-1/\beta} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {X_n} \to 0$ almost surely then $\mathbb{E}[\vert X_1\vert^{\beta}]$ is finite.

There is a hint:

> Why does it suffice to show that $\sum\limits_nP(\vert {X_n}\vert\gt n^{1/\beta})$ converges?

My thoughts on this:

I think the idea behind the hint is to indicate a way to show the finiteness of  $\mathbb{E} [\vert {X_1} \vert^{\beta}]$. I also thought about using convexity but I am unable to find any idea to start.

Comment: There are two parts in this. First, that the convergence of the series $\sum P(|X_n|>n^{1/\beta})$ implies (actually, is equivalent to) $|X_1|^\beta$ being integrable. Second, that the divergence of the series $\sum P(|X_n|>n^{1/\beta})$ implies that $n^{-1/\beta}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k$ diverges almost surely. Have you really no idea about showing either part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how to use the hint:
First notice that $\sum_n P(|X_n| > n^{\frac{1}{\beta}}) = \sum_n P(|X_n|^{\beta} > n)$. Since $|X_n|^{\beta}$ clearly has only values $\ge$, you can use the following representation of the expectation:

### $E[|X_n|^{\beta}] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(|X_n|^{\beta} > x) dx$.

Since $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ i.i.d, we can conclude:

### $E[|X_1|^{\beta}] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(|X_1|^{\beta} > x) dx = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} P(|X_1|^{\beta} > x) dx \le \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} P(|X_1|^{\beta} > n). $

Notice that the last inequality follows from the monotonicity of the probability measure.

Best Diamir